# Does Puppet check-in on startup if interval is 24 hours?

Tags: puppet

I'm confused as to whether puppet runs when the daemon turns on or if it waits for the run interval?

Say I have a device that has never run puppet before, Puppet is run as a service when Ubuntu starts.

The run interval is 24 hours. Does it run once on startup and then again in 24 hours? Or does it wait 24 hours before doing the first check-in?

If it is the later and the check-in doesn't happen on startup, is there a configuration that can be changed to allow checkup on startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether started in daemon mode or not, the Puppet agent ordinarily performs a catalog run immediately when it starts.  The main difference with daemon mode is that instead of terminating after one catalog run, the agent continues indefinitely, performing catalog runs periodically according to the run interval.

That behavior can be modulated somewhat by [the agent's `splay` and `splaylimit` settings](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/configuration.html#splay).  These can cause the agent to wait after startup for a period of time before performing the first catalog run.  That delay offsets the whole series of subsequent runs (if any): the interval between the first run and the second, the second and the third, *etc.* is unchanged.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Maybe are you aware of any official docs that describe such behaviour? May we rely on this behaviour and not be afraid to find at some point that it was changed?

Comment: @slava, this answer already links to the relevant docs for Puppet 5.5.  The Puppet docs site allows you to easily select another version (among those supported), to confirm that the docs are consistent.  I can affirm that the docs for the current latest version (6.14) say the same thing, and I can personally attest that these setting have worked as described since at least Puppet 2.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I've read the docs for the splay parameter more carefully and found the answer to my question. Sorry for bothering you.